# supervising daemons in debian

Tags: debian, supervisord, daemons, runit

We are running rabbitmq, redis and celery on a *Debian wheezy (oldstable)* linux server. all of them are installed as `init.d` scripts and started at boot time. we would like to keep an eye on them and get email alerts, if any of them goes down.

I have checked tools such as supervisord and runit. but, both of them seem to require the monitored process to be NOT daemons.

How to get this done? are there are other tools that get the job done? Pls. advise.

Comment: if you are running *Debian/wheezy* (as mentioned in the comment fo rsm's answer), you shouldn't call it *stable* (as it is no longer *stable* but *oldstable*, and this will change again). Better use unambiguous codenames (like *wheezy*)

Comment: check https://immortal.run probably can help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert of this but since Debian Jessie daemons are managed by `systemd`, I'd recommend you to use `sytemd` instead of `init.d`, and then use
`systemctl` to keep an eye over your daemons. I find that `systemctl` is great for monitoring, and probably there are even more tools on `systemd` for doing this.

To finish responding your question, by using `systemctl status <daemon>` you can know the status of a daemon, and I think that it also works for `init.d` scripts.

```
rsm@matrice:~$ systemctl status alienware-kbl
● alienware-kbl.service - alienware-kbl daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/alienware-kbl.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2015-07-04 10:30:17 CEST; 3h 7min ago
 Main PID: 1024 (alienware-kbl)
   CGroup: /system.slice/alienware-kbl.service
           ├─1024 /bin/bash /usr/bin/alienware-kbl --start-daemon
           └─1029 /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/share/alienware-kbl/Daemon.py --start-daemon
```

As a new/newbie programmer I find that making daemons over `systemd` is much easier than over `init.d`

Comment: we are running Debian Wheezy (the previous stable version) and systemd has to be added separately. since this is a production server, we need to carefully migrate from init to systemd. will check.

Answer (score 0):

Based on rsm's suggestion, we have created a simple tool called daemonsitter to watch over Systemd daemons. We have released this as an open source under apache license on github (https://github.com/dataglen/daemonsitter.git).